# How can I tell `Dot` to behave automatically linear?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, products, dot

I would like the number $a$ to be taken out:

```
$Assumptions = (a) \[Element] Complexes && (X) \[Element] 
    Matrices[{n, n}];

(a X).(a IdentityMatrix[n]) // FullSimplify
```

Is there a way to make this product to yield $a^2 X$ instead of `(X a).(a IdentityMatrix[n])`? And to simplify the `IdentityMatrix[n]` as well?

P.S. *Mathematica 10*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `TensorExpand[]` instead:

```
Assuming[a ∈ Complexes && X ∈ Matrices[{n, n}], 
         TensorExpand[(a X).(a IdentityMatrix[n])]]
   a^2 X
```