# Making Dot linear also for Kronecker Products

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, symbolic, dot

I want to manipulate expressions like

$$\big\{(aX+bY)\otimes Z \big\}\cdot \big\{U \otimes (c V+d W) \big\} $$

so that Mathematica (10) yields

$$ (aX U+bYU)\otimes(cZV+dZW) = acXU\otimes ZV+bcYU\otimes ZV+ adXU\otimes ZW +bd   YU\otimes ZW$$

for finite matrices of the same size (in capitals) and scalars (lowercase).

In the [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/223127/how-can-i-tell-dot-to-behave-automatically-linear) `TensorExpand` is used in order to take the scalars out of the `Dot` product. (I actually was used to TeX-SE forum once, where one has to put the core of the code only, but I oversimplified the linked question, and I apologize)

```
Assuming[(a | b | c) ∈ Reals && (X | Y) ∈ 
   Matrices[{n, n}], 
 TensorExpand[
  KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[n], a X].(b KroneckerProduct[c IdentityMatrix[n], Y])]] 
  (*...................................this ^ is culprit?...................*)
```

- If I remove the `b`, the result is: $ac  (1_n\otimes XY)$
- But if `b` is there, only intermediate steps are shown, even though  I used the `TensorExpand` as in that linked answer.

Why it does not work for Kronecker products?

Another remark is that substituting the `b` by a number, say $\pi$, then it does yield  $ac\pi  (1_n\otimes XY)$.

What am I missing for making `Dot` to simplify the computation?

P.S. I also tried the hint [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89183/factor-out-the-scalar-multiplier-for-the-dot-product-of-2x2-matrices?rq=1), namely

```
Unprotect[Dot];
Dot[a___, d_?NumericQ b_, c___] := d Dot[a, b, c]
Protect[Dot];
```

but it does not help.

Comment: I think my answer at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/165511 should help you. You can either define a new function that works well with symbolic expressions, or define a replacement rule for KroneckerProduct and Dot that pulls out scalars

Comment: @JulesLamers Yes, your linked answer is very promising and more instructive than upgrading my software!  (since I'd need to implement the cyclicity of the product, which I would have on traces).

Answer (score 4):

It looks like support for recognizing this property was added in M11.2 or M11.3. In M11.1 I get:

```
Assuming[
    (a|b|c) ∈ Reals && (X|Y) ∈ Matrices[{n,n}],
    TensorExpand[
        KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[n],a X].(b KroneckerProduct[c IdentityMatrix[n],Y])
    ]
]
```

> KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[n], 
>     a X].(b KroneckerProduct[c IdentityMatrix[n], Y])

while in M11.3 I get:

```
Assuming[
    (a|b|c) ∈ Reals && (X|Y) ∈ Matrices[{n,n}],
    TensorExpand[
        KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[n],a X].(b KroneckerProduct[c IdentityMatrix[n],Y])
    ]
]
```

> a b c KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[n], X.Y]

So, the simplest solution is to upgrade to a later version of Mathematica. I think it is possible to modify [`TensorExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorExpand) so it works properly in M10 as well, but I haven't investigated that possibility.